# Page in TabBarView does not run a function in initState

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have pages in a tabbarView which will run initstate each time it gets viewed. However when I load the screen, no data will be shown. Only when I reload the page will it appear.

This is part of the code for the page itself:

```
class TabViewReusablePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String rotaNumber;

  TabViewReusablePage({this.rotaNumber});

  @override
  _TabViewReusablePageState createState() => _TabViewReusablePageState();
}

class _TabViewReusablePageState extends State<TabViewReusablePage> {

List<ReusableListTile> paramedic = [];

void getInfo() async {
    final QuerySnapshot getdataPrm = await Firestore.instance
        .collection('Info')
        .document(widget.rotaNumber)
        .collection('Personnel')
        .getDocuments();



    getdataPrm.documents.forEach((f) {
      final title= f.data['title'];
      final code= f.data['code'];
      paramedic.add(ReusableListTile(
        title: title,
        code: code,
      ));
    });  
  }

@override
  void initState() {
    getInfo();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
class TabViewReusablePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String rotaNumber;

  TabViewReusablePage({this.rotaNumber});

  @override
  _TabViewReusablePageState createState() => _TabViewReusablePageState();
}

class _TabViewReusablePageState extends State<TabViewReusablePage> {

List<ReusableListTile> paramedic = [];

void getInfo() async {
    final QuerySnapshot getdataPrm = await Firestore.instance
        .collection('Info')
        .document(widget.rotaNumber)
        .collection('Personnel')
        .getDocuments();



    getdataPrm.documents.forEach((f) {
      final title= f.data['title'];
      final code= f.data['code'];

      //Update paramedic state

       setState((){
         paramedic.add(ReusableListTile(
           title: title,
           code: code,
         ));   
       });

    });  
  }

@override
  void initState() {
    getInfo();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }
```